# Calculating the Precession

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, precession

This is the [Anti gravity wheel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeyDf4ooPdo) video from Veritassium. I have a similar problem to  calculate the forces on arm.

[image]

How can I calculate the precession force pushing the arm vertically ?

Lets assume that 
the angles between shaft and arm is 90°
the angles between shaft and wheel is 90°

The wheel properties are
Mass - M<sub>wheel</sub> , 
Radius - R<sub>wheel</sub>,
Speed(rpm) - V<sub>wheel</sub>,

The length of shaft is  L<sub>shaft</sub>, and mass is M<sub>shaft</sub> though to keep it simple we can ignore the mass of shaft.
[image]

Comment: "Precession" is not a force (as shown above), but a torque. Actually it is neither as precession is a change in orientation about the first euler angle. Precession, Nutation, Spin being the three euler angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "precession force" acting at the point where the arm holds up the shaft. The force from the arm must balance Mg, and hence the vertically upwards force is just Mg.

However, the wheel has angular momentum, let's call it L (not to be confused with the length of the shaft) which equals $I\omega$, where $I$ is the moment of inertia around the axis of the shaft and $\omega$ is the angular frequency of revolution.

The force of gravity $\vec F$ acts on the wheel downwards, and the vector from the axis around which the shaft-wheel combination must rotate (it is held at the other end by the arm) is $\vec r$. This vector $\vec r$ points from the arm to the wheel. The torque generated by this if $\vec r \times \vec F$ and points horizontally, and hence the angular momentum precesses so that the change in its vector direction is horizontal. [Horizontal precession.]

P.S. Nice diagram - how did you make it (what software?)

Edit added in response to question in comments:

Corrections to your calculations: $I=mr^2/2$ (factor of 2 smaller). Also, $\omega$ in expression for $L$ should be 315, why 632?

Comment: Thanks! can you help me to understand this with an example ? frequency of revolution is 315 rad per sec, and Mwheel is 2kg and r of wheel is 10cm, if I understand correctly  I =mr^2, and L=Iω, so I = 2 * (0.1*0.1) and L= 0.02 * 632. as for software of diagram it is the MS paint :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the equation that solves the problem:
$$\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}=\vec{r}\wedge\vec{F}$$
In this case $\frac{d(IV_{wheel})}{dt}=rF\rightarrow IV_{Wheel}\Omega_{prec}=RMg$
from this equation you can get $\Omega_{prec}$ since it is the only unknown, the weight is unimportant because it is canceled

Comment: the shaft can rotate in horizontal axis of arm,  and the shaft is a rotor for wheel. Sorry I am not an expert in physics, I want to calculate at what RPM and Weight of wheel it will compensate the gravity force. So instead of falling down the shaft will rotate in horizontal axis as in video.